# Can I decorate my [DataMember] to generate restrictions in the WSDL?

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl

Thanks in advance to any one that can help.

I have had success building a SOAP service and test client in C# .Net VS2012 and have been using it to prep for an upcoming service we will deploy. The server will expose only a couple services but they will use a handful of classes that will expose around 300 [DataMembers].

The team lead is concerned that the WSDL that was generated for me when I access the service from the browser does not include restrictions on the various elements.

In other words, the generated WSDL I grabbed from the service website may look like this:

```
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="FirstName" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
```

But he suggests that we need something like this:

```
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="FirstName" >
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="18"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
```

I think his concern is once you add the service reference using the generated WSDL the client developer won't know about field limitations like max length, or pattern, etc.

I have already added both server side fault exceptions for various validations (including max length, pattern, empty strings, etc). I also have implemented DevTrends DataAnnotations in a small set to test how that works - works pretty good BTW.

But what I need to know is there a way to get those xs:restrictions into the WSDL from code. Is there a way to do this or do I have to do this by hand (there will be approx. 300 fields so I am reticent to do that)? Is this really necessary considering the other validation mechanisms I have put in place? Is there a better alternative that I am missing?

Thanks again!